# Visual Studio templates does not appear

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

i trying create a project with Visual Studio 2019 after a few months but im only see that:

[image]

Than i tried to open update vs and i saw this error after finishing update:

[image: How to fix this?]

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't read those errors in that language, but I would suggest two things, both in the VS installer:

1. Run a repair on your installation.
2. Make sure you have the relevant workloads installed.

While you're at it, consider upgrading to VS2022 if you can. Given you're on community edition, it's a free upgrade.